# How do I fix this "core_cm3.h" fatal error error while building a file in STMCube IDE?

Tags: c, embedded, stm32cubeide

I am trying to make an LED blinking program with the STMCube IDE but while building, I am getting the error:

*/Drivers/CMSIS/Device/ST/STM32F1xx/Include/stm32f103xb.h:132:10: fatal error: core_cm3.h: No such file or directory*

Sorry but I do not know how all this works, so if someone could explain to me what is wrong.

Comment: You need to download the CMSIS header files and include them in your project.